# Display data of the user after logging in

Tags: php, mysql

This is my form of `cus_login.php`:

```
<form method="post"  action="cus_login.php">
    <h2>LOG-IN</h2> <hr>

    <div id="message" > <?php if ($msg != "") echo $msg ?></div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="email_add" type="email" placeholder="Email...">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password...">
    </div>

    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOG IN">
</form>
```

The action is just above this file, which is the following:

```
<?php include 'includes/config.php';
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  


$email_add = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email_add']);
$password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if ($email_add == "" || $password == "")
  $msg = "Empty Fields! Type in your Email address and Password";
else {

  $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE email_add='$email_add'");

  if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
            $data = $sql->fetch_array();
            if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
                if ($data['confirm'] == 0)
                  $msg = "Please verify your email! Before logging in";
                else {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                    header("location: cus_prof.php");
                }
            } else
              $msg = "Wrong Password! Please enter again.";
  } else {
    $msg = "Wrong Email Address! Please enter again";
  }
} }?>
```

How do I display the info of the customers based on the email or id  to another page or file ... like a profile information page?

Comment: What *is* happening? What should happen? At a glance it looks like you have missing braces for the conditionals - maybe that's some kind of shorthand I don't know about - if so you should stop doing that. Do you get any errors? It's a bit unclear if you want someone to write code for a redirect, or it should be and doesn't. Are you redirected? (also put `exit;` after redirects)

Comment: put the code to get the userdata in your cus_prof.php file?

Comment: Does `header("location: cus_prof.php");` work? If so store the data from the DB in the session then output the session data on that page.

Comment: @James The brackets aren't needed if the next line is the only thing the conditional does. e.g. first example here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php (I also don't like it, but it is valid)

Comment: @chris85 Thanks, I presumed something awful like that was at play. *shudder*

Comment: hello everyone so this is my code.... @james

Comment: @ lollmbaowtfidgafgtfoohwtbs this is my code... when I logged in. It does direct to the cus_prof.php ... I just need the code the get the id of the user so that I can fetch the single row of data and echo it

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php 
    session_start();
   include 'includes/config.php';
    /*note in your config.php must have the session_start(); function as the first line just after
     opening php tag else session will not start and Your session variable will not be available */

    $msg="";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  


    $email_add = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['email_add']);
    $password = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if ($email_add == "" || $password == "")
      $msg = "Empty Fields! Type in your Email address and Password";
    else {

      $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE email_add='$email_add'");


      if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
                $data = $sql->fetch_array();
                if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
                    if ($data['confirm'] == 0)
                      $msg = "Please verify your email! Before logging in";
                    else {
                        // session_start(); this must be call in the first line of code before any other code
                        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    //here you can just add the data variable to the session`enter code here`
                        //$_SESSION['data'] = $data;
                        header("location: cus_prof.php");


                    }
                } else
                  $msg = "Wrong Password! Please enter again.";
      } else {
        $msg = "Wrong Email Address! Please enter again";
      }
    }
    }?>
// then in your cus_prof.php file

    <?php 
      include 'includes/config.php';
    $id =$_SESSION['id'];


      $sql = $con->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_customers WHERE id='$id'");
              if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
                        $data = $sql->fetch_array();
        //do whatever you want with the data in the $data array
        }

    ?>
```

I have just added the data variable to session that way you can access whatever is in the data variable through the session variable at any location.

Comment: i think i just need the data id.... once i got that one.... i'll use it on the other file... then i'll fetch the data based on that id... i just dont know how to code that part....